# Who is this fallen member from Young Justice: Invasion?

Tags: character, young-justice

In Young Justice S02E08, we got to know that Justice League avoid memorial of their fallen members in public display and kept it inside the Mount Justice.

We see four fallen members in the holograms:

[image]

If we go from left to right, First one is Artemis, second one is Robin (must be Jason Todd) and forth one is Blue Beetle (Ted Kord). But who is the 3rd one :

[image][image]

Who is she?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tula/Aquagirl

[image]

> You've seen  memorial  holograms for Jason Todd/Robin and Tula/Aquagirl. - [Station Eight - Ask Greg](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=20049)

Her death is mentioned in S2E3 "Alienated", mentioned around 14:08.

> **Superboy**: None of us wanted to believe this! How could you betray us?
>   **Aqualad**: You dare question me? After all of you let Tula die!
>   **Nightwing**: Kaldur that was a mission. Aquagirl knew the risks.

Comment: Aw, man, I was gonna answer this.

Comment: @CreationEdge Too bad so sad.

Comment: Well, I helped you at least, if you accept the edit ;)

Comment: It just skip from my head :/, I just forgot how she looks and have no idea that she even joined the YJ team.